# Derived colour looks different in different monitors?

Tags: css, colors

In my website I use the `#1ABC9B` as background colour. But it looks differently in different monitors. In MAC systems and smart phones it looks little lighter green as compared to other laptop monitors in which it looks like dark green. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3):

It is normal, it can vary from monitor to monitor. You can play with the the colours configuration to try to get it similar.

On mac systems: System preferences -> Display -> Color

try to set a different Display Profile

Comment: But it is not happening for all colours?@ShinDarth